# Polymer script only component for function modularization

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Can I have a script only component in `Polymer` to hold all my helper functions used across application? I am not sure what is the recommended way of having reusable `functions`, `constants` that can be imported across components ?

```
<dom-module id="helper-functions">  
  <script>
    (function() {
        var helper1 = function() { ... };
        var helper2 = function() { ... };
        Polymer({
            is : 'helper-functions' 
        });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "could" do this, but it depends on what those helper functions are doing and whether they need any "Polymer" features.

One way to package up this sort of thing is as a "behavior", and seems to be the way that the Polymer Elements themselves are doing things.  Split your helpers into functional areas and make each a separate behavior, and then include the behavior in those elements that need it. Here's an example to show how its done (I am including all my behaviors in the PAS namespace.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<script>
window.PAS = window.PAS || {};

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var dialogs = [];

  PAS.DialogBehaviour = {
    attached: function() {
      dialogs.push(this);  //Capture all dialogs as they start up
    },
    _requestClose: function() {
      this.async(function() { //Wait a second to allow inflight ajax to have a chance to finish
        dialogs.forEach(function(dialog) {
          if (dialog !== this) {
            dialog._forceClose();
          }
        },this);
      },1000);
    },
    _forceClose: function() {
      //abstract
    }

  };

})();

</script>
```

I then include it in my elements like ...

```
Polymer({
  is: 'pas-standin',
  behaviors: [AKC.Route,PAS.DialogBehaviour,Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior],
  listeners: {
    'pas-error': '_closeDialog'
  },
```

But for pure javascript functions, I have added my helper functions in my app.js file. I don't have that many at the moment, and I suspect if I did it would be a sign that I haven't designed the right elements.